# How do I fix my onChange event to get the event.target.value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the code below and before the validation implementation (useForm, yupResolver and Yup), the handleChange function was working just fine. If I console.log the value variable, I get nothing. It seems that it is not registering what I'm typing in the input field. Besides, I get the error below on my browser:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function
    at executeSearch (index.tsx:64:1)
    at createFormControl.ts:1045:1
```

How can I fix this? Sorry, I'm relatively new with TypeScript and React.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, FormEventHandler } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import Loader from "react-ts-loaders";

import { WeatherApiVariables } from "../../../variables";
import { inputSchema } from "../../../validations/schema";

import lowTemperature from "../../../assets/icons/low-temperature-icon.svg";
import highTemperature from "../../../assets/icons/high-temperature-icon.svg";
import styles from "./weather-api.module.scss";

export function WeatherApi() {
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState<string>("");
  const [cityWeather, setCityWeather]: any = useState<{}>({});
  const [cityWeatherForecast, setCityWeatherForecast]: any = useState<[]>([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  }: any = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(inputSchema),
  });

  async function getCurrentWeather(cityName: string): Promise<any> {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${WeatherApiVariables.token}&q=${cityName}&${WeatherApiVariables.airQuality}&${WeatherApiVariables.dataLanguage}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  async function getWeatherForecast(cityName: string): Promise<any> {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${WeatherApiVariables.token}&q=${cityName}&${WeatherApiVariables.airQuality}&${WeatherApiVariables.dataLanguage}&days=${WeatherApiVariables.forecastDays}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const currentWeather = await getCurrentWeather(cityName);
      const weatherForecast = await getWeatherForecast(cityName);
      setCityWeather(currentWeather);
      setCityWeatherForecast(weatherForecast);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [cityName]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(value);
  };

  const executeSearch: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (
    event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const transformedText = value
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    setCityName(transformedText);
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.search_container}>
        <h2>Busque por uma cidade</h2>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(executeSearch)}
          className={styles.search_form}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            name="searchField"
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Ex: Blumenau, Santa Catarina"
            {...register("searchField")}
          />
          <p>{errors.searchField?.message}</p>
          <input
            type="submit"
            className={styles.search_btn}
            value="Pesquisar"
          />
        </form>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.current_weather_section}>
        {loading ? (
          <Loader className="loader" type="roller" size={150} />
        ) : (
          <>
            {!cityWeather.location ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <div className={styles.current_weather_container}>
                <h2> Condição climática atual em:</h2>
                <h3>
                  {cityWeather.location.name}, {cityWeather.location.region}
                </h3>
                <div className={styles.condition_container}>
                  <span>{cityWeather.current.condition.text}</span>
                  <img
                    alt="ícone da condição atual do tempo"
                    src={cityWeather.current.condition.icon}
                  ></img>
                </div>
                <span>Temperatura atual: {cityWeather.current.temp_c} °C</span>
                <span>
                  Sensação térmica: {cityWeather.current.feelslike_c} °C
                </span>
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </div>

      {!cityWeatherForecast.forecast ? (
        ""
      ) : (
        <>
          <h2>Previsão para os próximos dias</h2>
          <section className={styles.weather_forecast_section}>
            {cityWeatherForecast.forecast.forecastday.map(
              (item: any, key: string) => {
                const dateUnix = (item.date_epoch + 86400) * 1000;
                const newDate = new Date(dateUnix);
                const forecastWeekDay = newDate.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
                  weekday: "long",
                });
                const forecastDay = newDate.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
                  day: "numeric",
                });
                return (
                  <ul key={key} className={styles.weather_forecast_list}>
                    <li>
                      <h2>
                        {forecastWeekDay} - {forecastDay}
                      </h2>
                      <div className={styles.forecast_condition_container}>
                        <span>{item.day.condition.text}</span>
                        <img
                          alt="ícone do clima"
                          src={item.day.condition.icon}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <p>
                        Poss. chuva: {item.day.daily_chance_of_rain} % -{" "}
                        {item.day.totalprecip_mm} mm
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <img
                          src={lowTemperature}
                          alt="termômetro - temperatura baixa"
                        />
                        {item.day.mintemp_c} °C
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <img
                          src={highTemperature}
                          alt="termômetro - temperatura alta"
                        />
                        {item.day.maxtemp_c} °C
                      </p>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                );
              }
            )}
          </section>
        </>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening on your `executeSearch` function and is because you're using that function in conjunction with the `useForm` prop `handleSubmit` if you look the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit) the `handleSubmit` function accepts a another function that has three arguments **data** (which is the form structure shape you want to give your form) the **errors** (which has an object containing the incorrect form items) and the **event** Object (which has all the event information):

`((data: Object, e?: Event) => void, (errors: Object, e?: Event) => void) => Function`

So that means that what your `executeSearch` function is using the data object as the event, so it is not the actual event itself, is the `formData`. You probably don't need the `event.preventDefault()` because react hook form handles that for you, in case you want to use the event for something else you must use the right parameter like this:

```
 const executeSearch = (
    _data,
    _errors,
    event
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const transformedText = value
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    setCityName(transformedText);
    setValue("");
  };
```

I highly suggest to read the TS documentation for react hook form, once you get used to it, you won't want to do the forms yourself again.

https://react-hook-form.com/ts

Also is this is very confusing for you, I also suggest to read the TS docs and have a better understanding of types and interfaces, so you can use react hook form as it is intended and use your own interfaces and types in conjunction with it.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html#interfaces

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, but I'm still confused of what I have to change in order to make the executeSearch function work. Could you please show it to me?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it correctly:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import Loader from "react-ts-loaders";

import { WeatherApiVariables } from "../../../variables";
import { inputSchema } from "../../../validations/schema";

import lowTemperature from "../../../assets/icons/low-temperature-icon.svg";
import highTemperature from "../../../assets/icons/high-temperature-icon.svg";
import styles from "./weather-api.module.scss";
interface ISearch {
  searchField: string;
}

export function WeatherApi() {
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState<string>("");
  const [cityWeather, setCityWeather]: any = useState<{}>({});
  const [cityWeatherForecast, setCityWeatherForecast]: any = useState<[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const {
    register,
    resetField,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  }: any = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(inputSchema),
  });

  async function getCurrentWeather(cityName: string): Promise<any> {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${WeatherApiVariables.token}&q=${cityName}&${WeatherApiVariables.airQuality}&${WeatherApiVariables.dataLanguage}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  async function getWeatherForecast(cityName: string): Promise<any> {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${WeatherApiVariables.token}&q=${cityName}&${WeatherApiVariables.airQuality}&${WeatherApiVariables.dataLanguage}&days=${WeatherApiVariables.forecastDays}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const currentWeather = await getCurrentWeather(cityName);
      const weatherForecast = await getWeatherForecast(cityName);
      setCityWeather(currentWeather);
      setCityWeatherForecast(weatherForecast);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [cityName]);

  const handleSearch = (data: ISearch) => {
    const transformedText = data.searchField
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    setCityName(transformedText);
    resetField("searchField");
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.search_container}>
        <h2>Busque por uma cidade</h2>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSearch)}
          className={styles.search_form}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            name="searchField"
            placeholder="Ex: Blumenau, Santa Catarina"
            {...register("searchField")}
          />
          <p>{errors.searchField?.message}</p>
          <input
            type="submit"
            className={styles.search_btn}
            value="Pesquisar"
          />
        </form>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.current_weather_section}>
        {loading ? (
          <Loader className="loader" type="roller" size={150} />
        ) : (
          <>
            {!cityWeather.location ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <div className={styles.current_weather_container}>
                <h2> Condição climática atual em:</h2>
                <h3>
                  {cityWeather.location.name}, {cityWeather.location.region}
                </h3>
                <div className={styles.condition_container}>
                  <span>{cityWeather.current.condition.text}</span>
                  <img
                    alt="ícone da condição atual do tempo"
                    src={cityWeather.current.condition.icon}
                  ></img>
                </div>
                <span>Temperatura atual: {cityWeather.current.temp_c} °C</span>
                <span>
                  Sensação térmica: {cityWeather.current.feelslike_c} °C
                </span>
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </div>

      {!cityWeatherForecast.forecast ? (
        ""
      ) : (
        <>
          <h2>Previsão para os próximos dias</h2>
          <section className={styles.weather_forecast_section}>
            {cityWeatherForecast.forecast.forecastday.map(
              (item: any, key: string) => {
                const dateUnix = (item.date_epoch + 86400) * 1000;
                const newDate = new Date(dateUnix);
                const forecastWeekDay = newDate.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
                  weekday: "long",
                });
                const forecastDay = newDate.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
                  day: "numeric",
                });
                return (
                  <ul key={key} className={styles.weather_forecast_list}>
                    <li>
                      <h2>
                        {forecastWeekDay} - {forecastDay}
                      </h2>
                      <div className={styles.forecast_condition_container}>
                        <span>{item.day.condition.text}</span>
                        <img
                          alt="ícone do clima"
                          src={item.day.condition.icon}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <p>
                        Poss. chuva: {item.day.daily_chance_of_rain} % -{" "}
                        {item.day.totalprecip_mm} mm
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <img
                          src={lowTemperature}
                          alt="termômetro - Temperatura baixa"
                        />
                        {item.day.mintemp_c} °C
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <img
                          src={highTemperature}
                          alt="termômetro - Temperatura alta"
                        />
                        {item.day.maxtemp_c} °C
                      </p>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                );
              }
            )}
          </section>
        </>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}
```